# Widget not updating on creation? - Android

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

I've got a widget that shows weather when a button is clicked on it. The widget is supposed to do this update when it's first created, however that's not the case. I have to manually click-update it once I put it on homescreen.

**Q. How to I update the widget automatically once it's created?**

Things I've tried:

1. Use onEnabled inside Widget Provider
2. Use onRecieve inside Widget Provider

My WidgetProvider:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.rButton, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

        pushWidgetUpdate(context, views);
    }
    public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("update");
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews views) {
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, views);
    }
}
```

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class WidgetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    double lat, lon;
    String xtemp, xmaxtemp, xmintemp, xcity, xweather, provider, weatherpic;
    Location loc;
    LocationManager mlocManager;
    //======================================= OnReceive Method
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("update")) {
                new MyAsyncTask2().execute(context);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public class MyAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, String> {
    //Does all the update for the weather and shows it on the textViews                  
    } 
}
```

I'm new to Widget programming, let me know if I can make any optimizations! :)